# Completing the sentence "By this time tomorrow....."

Tags: future-tense, future-time

Ok. So I am having trouble completing this sentence correctly

By this time tomorrow

1. I will be gone
2. I will have gone [future perfect ? ]
3. I would be gone.

I am starting to think that 3 isn't right.

Is 1 or 2 right ? If no when to use the other one?

Also along wih correct answer, can anyone tell me the rule which explains why it is correct?

Comment: *will have gone...* The future perfect. Not sure why 'been' is included.

Comment: All three are possible given an appropriate context.  **gone** can act as subject complement/predicate adjective with BE. **gone** can combine with auxiliary **have** to form a perfect tense. *I would be gone by this time tomorrow if it weren't for the fact that the airport has been shut down on account of the blizzard.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one 'future perfect' is the right one because you are talking about tomorrow and 'tomorrow' hasn't come yet.

Comment: Thank you. why not "will be" ? I know it is not future perfect, but it sounds right.